# Form validation throws a strict warning

Tags: forms, 8

I am using the form validation in `hook_form_alter()` as follows.

```
$form['#validate'][] = '\Drupal\module_name\Controller\MyController::_field_p_servicename_validate';
```

In the controller I am defining it as follows.

```
public function _field_p_servicename_validate(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}
```

It throws the following exception.

> Strict warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method Drupal\module_name\Controller\MyController::_field_p_servicename_validate() should not be called statically in Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->executeValidateHandlers() (line 88 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php)

What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are contexts where Drupal allows you to use a notation like  `'\Drupal\module_name\Controller\MyController::_field_p_rpservicename_validate'` to refer to a public function of an object. In the case of validation handlers, since Drupal is calling them with `call_user_func_array()`, with a notation like `'\Drupal\module_name\Controller\MyController::_field_p_rpservicename_validate'` you are referring to a static function of a class.

Change  the definition of that method as follows, and your code will work.

```
public static function _field_p_rpservicename_validate(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}
```

Keep in mind that a static method cannot use `$this`.

Comment: If this is in the form object, you can also specific the callback as '::_field_p_rpservicename_validate', that's a special form callback feature, starting with :: means a method on the form object.